# Can't get drone.io CI to share files between pipelin steps

Tags: drone.io

here is my `.drone.yml`:

```
pipeline:
  test:
  image: node:10
  commands:
    - npm install --production
    - npm run build --production

publish:
  image: plugins/docker
  repo: myhub/image_name
    when:
      event: push
      branch: master
```

the command `npm run build` creates a folder named `build` with static files inside. However, the publish step fails when building the docker image. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY build build
```

The error being: `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder090186817/build: no such file or directory time="2018-05-28T21:19:25Z" level=fatal msg="exit status 1"`

So I don't quite understand how to build some files in one step, and copy them in the docker publish step...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So anything in the workspace will get shared to the next step ;)

Are you able to build the docker image without drone with just docker build .?

ie. You might want to try to change `COPY build build` to be `COPY ./build /app/build` or the something like it.